# OO PHP question regarding arrays

Tags: php

I'm trying to learn object oriented PHP by porting some of the simple exercises I've learnt in Java to PHP. This is one of them, to calculate the total salary of 3 people.

I'm apparently having a problem with the array in the family class - php gives an error about "Undefined variable: a_family" on line 32. Could anybody point me in the correct direction?

```
<?php
    class person {
        private $name;
        private $salary;

        //constructor
        function __construct($given_name, $given_salary) {
            $this->name = $given_name;
            $this->salary = $given_salary;
        }

        //getter for salary
        function get_salary() {
            return $this->salary;
        }

    }

    class family {
        private $a_family;

        function __construct() {
            $a_family = array();
        }

        function add_family_member($given_person) {
            $a_family[] = $given_person;
        }

        function get_total_salary() {
            $total_salary = 0;
            foreach ($a_family as $member) {
                $total_salary = $total_salary + $member->get_salary();
            }

            return $total_salary;
        }
    }

    $mum = new person("Mummy", 500);
    $dad = new person("Daddy", 1500);
    $sis = new person("Sister", 20);

    $my_family = new family();

    $my_family->add_family_member($mum);
    $my_family->add_family_member($dad);
    $my_family->add_family_member($sis);

    $family_income = $my_family->get_total_salary();

?>

<!-- start HTML -->
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <p>My total family income is $<?php echo $family_income; ?>.</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: ah i see! thanks everyone for your responses. much appreciated! :)

Comment: FYI, you should pick an answer that answered your question, assuming one has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike java, in PHP the `this` keyword is mandatory for referencing instance variables even when there is no ambiguity. You've done it correctly in your person class. You need to use `this` in your family class too.

```
$this->a_family = array();

...

$this->a_family[] = $given_person;

...

foreach ($this->a_family as $member) {

...
```

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
$this->a_family = array();
```

and:

```
$this->a_family[] = $given_person;
```

just like you've done in the first class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be referencing $a_family as $this->a_family instead within your functions.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
$this->a_family
```

because you a referring to a variable in the class scope, even if you have set `$a_family` to `private`.

`$a_family` only refers to the variable in the current method.